# Correct way to check return value from system command

Tags: c, posix

I have a C program which calls an AWK script which returns with exit code zero or one. However the call to `system` in my C program returns 256 when the exit code from the AWK script is one. Where is this documented? Is this value system dependent or is one always translated into 255 + 1?

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int exitCode;

    exitCode = system("awk '{ exit 0 }' test.c");
    printf("%d\n", exitCode);
    exitCode = system("awk '{ exit 1 }' test.c");
    printf("%d\n", exitCode);
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -o test -Wall test.c
$ ./test
0
256
```

Comment: See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html and https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html

Comment: According to the [`system(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) manpage you should be using the `WEXITSTATUS` macro on the return value.

Comment: `man wait` should help you about the `WEXITSTATUS` mentioned in above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) for `system`, it states the following regarding the return value:

> The return value of system() is one of the following:
>
> •  If command is NULL, then a nonzero value if a shell is
> available, or 0 if no shell is available.
>
> •  If a child process could not be created, or its status could
> not be retrieved, the return value is -1 and errno is set to
> indicate the error.
>
> •  If a shell could not be executed in the child process, then
> the return value is as though the child shell terminated by
> calling _exit(2) with the status 127.
>
> •  If all system calls succeed, then the return value is the
> termination status of the child shell used to execute command.
> (The termination status of a shell is the termination status
> of the last command it executes.)
>
> In the last two cases, the return value is a "wait status" that
> can be examined using the macros described in waitpid(2).  (i.e.,
> WIFEXITED(), WEXITSTATUS(), and so on).
>
> system() does not affect the wait status of any other children.

So to see the actual exit status of the program, you need to first need to check if -1 is returned and if not use `WEXITSTATUS` on the value to extract the command's exit status.

```
exitCode = system("awk '{ exit 0 }' test.c");
if (exitCode == -1) {
    perror("system failed");
} else {
    printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(exitCode));
}
exitCode = system("awk '{ exit 1 }' test.c");
if (exitCode == -1) {
    perror("system failed");
} else {
    printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(exitCode));
}
```

Comment: Technically check for `WIFEXITED` before using `WEXITSTATUS`.